# Unable to play m.youtube.com video in BlackBerry simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

When I try to play video from m.youtube.com I get an error:

`an error has occured attempting to play media.`

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are running the MDS Simulator (start it before the simulator), otherwise most applications that use networking on the simulator (including the web browser) will not work.

EDIT: as noted below, YouTube mobile uses RTSP which isn't supported in the simulators

Comment: as i am able open the m.youtube.com but when i clicked on "watch video" it didnt play.and also able to open all other websites.

Comment: After a bit of poking around, it seems that mobile YouTube uses RTSP which isn't supported over BIS/BES (and therefore the MDS simulator).  So it probably isn't possible to do it over the simulator.  You'll have to use a real device.  See http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-Test-Audio-RTSP-application-on-Simulator/m-p/209046 for more info.

Comment: As i have tried it in device it works but in simulator it not works.thankx a lot marc for replying.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with different versions of the OS in your emulator. Be aware, however, that Blackberry support for Flash video is virtually nonexistent even on their handsets, so you're bound to run into issues.